# Android WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED Parse

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, mms

I've made a simple BroadcastReceiver to catch the MMS before the native app. Now I want to parse the data of this MMS in order to do some work on it.

In my `onReceive` method, I've the following code:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(MMS_RECEIVED) && intent.getType().equals("application/vnd.wap.mms-message"))
{
    Log.e(">>>>>", "MMS");

    try
    {
        byte[] pushData = intent.getByteArrayExtra("pdu");

        // What to do with that ?
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // TODO Send notification
}
```

How can I retrieve the MMS data and download the associated part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be useful. The was mms is handled is quite different to SMS and the below link is similar to what I do: https://github.com/romannurik/dashclock/blob/master/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/phone/SmsExtension.java

Comment: Well thanks for your answer but that's not really what I need. I don't need to read the phone database as the MMS isn't inserted yet. I need to parse the MMS data (Hex data obviously) to get the sender phone number and the URL to the content.

Comment: Looks like the code in that link was moved to GitHub now: https://github.com/romannurik/dashclock/blob/master/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/phone/SmsExtension.java

Comment: Also, not sure why this is marked as the accepted answer. Have you found a solution for this question?